# Remember me в Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно в классе выставить **remember me** для **Spring Security**. Вот метод аутентификации пользователя. Можно ли как-нибудь в этом методе выставить **remember me**?

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("authenticationManager")
protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

public void authenticateUserAndSetSession(String username,String password, HttpServletRequest request) {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);

    request.getSession();

    token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request));
    Authentication authenticatedUser = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticatedUser);

}
```

Вот конфигурация для **remember me**

```html
 <remember-me
                user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService"
                key="rem-me-key"
                remember-me-parameter="remember-me-param"
                remember-me-cookie="my-remember-me"
                token-validity-seconds="86400"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно использовать `RememberMeAuthenticationProvider` и `TokenBasedRememberMeServices` для аутентификации